# Apacheで全ての場合に同じファイルを表示する方法を教えてください

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Apacheで全ての場合に同じファイルを表示する方法を教えてください。

例:
localhost/index.php index.phpを表示
localhost/hoge index.phpを表示
↑こんな感じになるようにしたいです

Answer (score 0):

laravel でやっている .htaccess が参考になると思います。
具体的には以下のような箇所が該当するので、試してみてください。

```
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

[説明記事](https://www.suzu6.net/posts/239-laravel-htaccess/)